# What is the output document of a proofreader?

Tags: word-choice

After a proofreader has compared a typeset manuscript with the original, and highlighted any discrepancies, what is the resultant document called? Is there a special term for a proofread document (especially one covered with proofreaders' marks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant terms include *proofed copy*, *marked* or *marked-up* copy, *revised* copy, and *next revision*.

A typeset manuscript with highlighted discrepancies or with proofreaders' marks would be referred to as a proofed copy or marked-up copy.  A corrected manuscript (that is, a copy printed after indicated changes are complete) is a revised copy or a next revision.

As noted in wikipedia's [Proofreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofreading) article, organization-specific terms (like *bounce*, *bump*, *revise*) may be used to refer to copies that have been proof-read:

> Proofs are then returned to the typesetter or graphic artist for correction. Correction-cycle proofs will typically have one descriptive term, such as *bounce, bump,* or *revise* unique to the department or organization and used for clarity to the strict exclusion of any other.

Comment: The term I am familiar with is _proof_, it is also the one used in your wikipedia quote.